# Find system service by conf file

Tags: systemd, proxy, services

**Setup:**
The task is to remove all proxy settings. Now I came across a `proxy.conf` file at `/root/http-proxy.conf` that contains this (with different IP ):

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://10.10.10.10:1234"
```

**Question:**
How can I figure out the corresponding service given the conf file? Assuming there is a service running that uses this conf file.

**Notes:**
Because if there is a service using this file, there might be no need for that service anymore and I would like to remove both the service and the conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that this file is being used by anything at all. But to confirm this, you can do the following:

- Looking for other configuration files referencing `/root/http-proxy.conf`:

```
grep -Ri "/root/http-proxy.conf" /root/
grep -Ri "/root/http-proxy.conf" /etc/
```

- Looking for processes reading this file (probably won't find anything):

```
lsof | grep "/root/http-proxy.conf"
```

- Check if this variable is actually set:

```
env | grep "10.10.10.10:1234"
```